# How do I add days to a variable created using the Date() API?

Tags: javascript, date

The following code gets me the date format as *DD.MM.YYYY*, which is what I want:

```
const todayDate = new Date().toLocaleString("ru", {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: '2-digit'
      })
```

How do I add days to `todayDate` (for example, add four days)?

Comment: Please refer moment.js . It is a library for Dates and related formatting in JS

Comment: `new Date(Date.now() + 4 * 86400000)` seems decent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, first add the day then do the conversion:

```js
var todayDate = new Date()

var newDate = todayDate.setTime( todayDate.getTime() + 4 * 86400000 );// adding 4 days

var dt=new Date (newDate);
console.log(dt.toLocaleString("ru", {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: '2-digit'
      }));
```

Another way similar using `setDate`.

```js
var todayDate = new Date()

var newDate = todayDate.setDate( todayDate.getDate() + 4);// adding 4 days

var dt=new Date (newDate);
console.log(dt.toLocaleString("ru", {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: '2-digit'
      }));
```

You should use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) if you are going to play around with `date` , it has a lot to offer.

Comment: Why not use `date.setDate()`?

Comment: @Rajesh  setDate will also work , i guess converting to timestamp will be safer.

Comment: @Suchit—adding days by adding multiples of 8.64e7 milliseconds isn't a good idea as not all days are 24 hours long.